# Is "of" necessary in this sentence: "They discussed a Tennessee school board's banning of a novel."

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-construction, idiomatic-language, gerunds

**They discussed a Tennessee school board's banning of a novel.**

When I read the sentence, **"the banning of a novel"** did not sound right to me. I am not quite sure whether or not we need **"of"** after **"banning"**, because we simply can say **"banning a novel"**. We would not say **"banning of a novel"**

So, in my opinion the sentence should have been like this: **They discussed a Tennessee school board's banning a novel.** (There is no "of")

Without **"of"** the sentence seems more grammatical, doesn't it?

However, I am not native, so I am not 100% sure about my conclusion. Is it **"banning of something"**, or **"banning something?"**

Comment: Isn’t there an ‘of’ because they’re referring to it as a noun? They are referring to the ban itself, not the action of it.

Comment: They are both fine. The difference is grammatical: in "the banning of a novel", "banning" is a noun with the _of_ PP as its complement, while in "banning a novel", "banning" is a verb with "a novel" as its direct object.

Comment: @BillJ There is a difference in terms of how much territory is covered in one and not the other. That's the whole point. The Taming of the Shrew is not Taming the Shrew.

Comment: No: The difference is purely grammatical.

Comment: @ynus There is no semantic difference between _They discussed a Tennessee school board's banning of a novel_ and _They discussed a Tennessee school board's banning a novel_.

Comment: The difference is stylistic. As I said: The Taming of the Shrew is what Shakespeare called it. Not: Taming the Shrew. I trust the Bard over anything CGEL says or even you. The Crying of Lot 49, too. There are many literary examples and examples in titles, as well.

Comment: We're talking here of the OP's example, not literary ones, and especially not titles. Compare these examples "I resented his questioning of my motives and "I resented his questioning my motives". Other considerations aside, they may be construed as having the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

1. They discussed a Tennessee school board's banning of a novel.
2. They discussed a Tennessee school board's banning a novel.

Grammar-wise, they are both fine. However, 1) is slightly more formal.

Compare:
**Banning a book is a terrible thing**. [*emphasizes the action* only]
**The banning of a book is a terrible thing**. [goes to the overall idea given by the noun phrase; the **entire process**; not just the action]

What is indeed terrible is the banning of a/the book. Not simply the action of banning. It is an entire process, right?

Think of Shakespeare's The Taming of the Shrew. He didn't write: Taming the Shrew. I thought this was a good example of the point I am trying to make here.

Comment: thanks for the great comment. In addition to 2 sentences above, if I made up another sentence with almost the same structure, then what would it emphasize: "They discussed a Tennessee school board banning a novel." (no "of" and no "apostrophe"). So, in this form, does this sentence also emphasizes the "action", or does it emphasize the "school" ?

Comment: @yunus You are repeating what I told you. Leaving out the "of" and "a" emphasizes the action: the banning. It does not emphasize the process at work in doing so like the "of a" version.

Comment: ok I understand your point. Talking of such structures, another sentence comes to my head: "He is against Britain leaving the EU." Then this sentence emphasizes the action. (no "of" and no "apostrophe").  So, if I want to emphasize "the overall idea" not "the action", should I say "....Britain's leaving of the EU?

Comment: @yunus Yes,  Britain's leaving the EU, versus Britain's leaving of the EU, for me, works the same way for me. I think you will find most English language editors would probably agree with me.

Comment: I appreciate your comments. Here is another structure from the BBC which seems to have same meaning (but formed without an apostrophe): "Brexit: What you need to know about the UK leaving the EU." As you see, it uses neither of the previous 2 structure both with an apostrophe. So, can we say, this one might be a third alternative to "Britain's leaving the EU", or "Britain's leaving of the EU,"?

Comment: "the UK leaving the EU" is just part of the sentence. There, you could not use: What you need to know about the leaving of the EU by Britain. It is awkward there. Not necessary. They are defining Brexit. "What you need to know about my leaving home." not my leaving of home. :)

Comment: I am not sure if I understood correctly what you said. I think you mean "my leaving of home" is grammatically wrong. If it is wrong, then do you mean "... Britain's leaving of the EU," is also wrong. I am confused. "my leaving of home" has the same structure as "Britain's leaving of the EU". So, if one is wrong, the other must be wrong. Is that right?

Comment: Leaving [home or a place] is a quasi-idiom. No, I do not mean Britain's leaving of the EU is flat out wrong. It is just very awkward and unnecessary in that particular sentence that defines BREXIT.

Comment: Using a gerund form with "of" requires a strong feeling of an agent and a patient and not just a subject and an object.  "Leaving a place" does not invoke a strong image of an effect on the object (the place) and so "the leaving of a place" does not sound as good as the "banning of a book."

Comment: Similarly, you would not use that structure with emotions.  You would not talk about your "hating of bad people" or your "loving of your spouse."  You would have to say "hatred of bad peope" and "love of your spouse" using the equivalent nouns.  But you could talk about "Britain's abandoning of the EU to its fate" or its "exit from the EU."